# Can I use a professional killstreak kit on a killstreak weapon?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I put a killstreak kit on a named strange weapon. What would happen if I were to use a professional killstreak set on it? Would the strange and/or name still stay but the effect would change?

Answer (score 4):

You can not use a Professional Kill Streak kit on a weapon with a kit already on it (same with all kits), you must remove the Specialized Part of the Weapon using the restore button, and then apply the new kit to it. Old effects (such as tags, S. Parts, and qualities) will stay.